# What does "<employee>" mean in the following code: List<Employee><employee> employees = new List<Employee><employee>();

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I am reading an MVC 5 tutorial ([Learn MVC Project in 7 days – Day 2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/897559/Learn-MVC-Project-in-days-Day)).
It says to use this code:

```
List<Employee><employee> employees = new List<Employee><employee>();
```

I get a red underline. I understand I am trying to create a list of type Employee. (There is an Employee class.) But why don't I do it like this:

```
List<Employee>employees = new List<Employee>();
```

What does the `<employee>` part of the code do? Why do I need it? It's just giving me a red underline. Maybe I need to upgrade to MVC 5 from MVC 4? I'm using Visual Studio 2012 (MVC 4).

Comment: It's a typo in the tutorial.

Comment: @discosultan, make it an answer then :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a typo in the tutorial. You can check [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) that creating a List has no implementations of `List<type><othertype>`.

You may pass a `int32` value or `IEnumerable<T>` which will specify your list size, however `List<T><T>` simply does not compile.

Edit: As pointed out in the comments by Ant P, nothing in C# allows for `Anything<T><T>`, so if you ever run across that, it will not compile.

Comment: Neither does `Anything<T><T>` for that matter, because that is not valid C# syntax.

Comment: Good point. I'll add it to the answer...although not specifically for this question, useful general knowledge for future readers.

Answer (score 3):

It's a typo in the tutorial.

You can read about [Generics here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx).

The correct code would be as you said yourself. You're just creating a new list which can only hold employee objects.